# confirm-ack and confirm-nack channel not getting invoked

Tags: spring-amqp

I am trying to configure the ack & nack channel and am getting the error like
    "Only one confirm call back channel can be configured at a time"

```
Below are the things which I tried:

1. confirm-correlation-expression="#root"  //no result found

2. Changed the amqp template like below

 <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" publisher-confirms="true" publisher-returns="true" />

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" mandatory="true" /> <!-- for nacks -->

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />


            />

The error was not there but the ack channel is not getting invoked.

Can anyone help me on this?
```

Here the MQ config

```
<rabbit:template id="nonTransactionalRabbitTemplate"
                     connection-factory="nonTransactionalConnectionFactory"
                     mandatory="true"
                     channel-transacted="false"
                     confirm-callback="confirmCallback"
                     return-call`enter code here`back="returnCallback" />
  <rabbit:connection-factory id="nonTransactionalConnectionFactory"
                               connection-factory="rabbitClientConnectionFactory"
                               publisher-confirms="true"
                               publisher-returns="true"/>

  <rabbit:connection-factory id="nonTransactionalConnectionFactory"
                               connection-factory="rabbitClientConnectionFactory"
                               publisher-confirms="true"
                               publisher-returns="true"/>


    <bean id="rabbitClientConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory" >
        <property name="uri" value="${mq.uri}" />
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="30" />
    </bean>
```

Here is my outbound adapter

```
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc"
                                       routing-key="xyz"
                                       amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
                                       confirm-correlation-expression="payload"
                                       confirm-ack-channel="successRespTransformChannel"
                                       confirm-nack-channel="failureRespTransformChannel"
                                       return-channel="failureRespTransformChannel"
                                       mapped-request-headers="*"
```

Here is my service activator

```
   <chain input-channel="successRespTransformChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
        <error-channel ref="failed-publishing" />
        </int:header-enricher>
        <service-activator id="successResp" expression="@abc.addRequestTracking(payload.id,'success')"/>

    </chain>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the template in the adapter, you must **NOT** set your own callbacks

```
     confirm-callback="confirmCallback"
     return-callback="returnCallback" />
```

The adapter sets itself as the callback for both confirms and returns. This fails since you have already set the callbacks.

```
 <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" mandatory="true" /> <!-- for nacks -->
```

`mandatory` enables returns, not nacks.

**EDIT**

I have no idea what you are doing wrong. I just wrote a quick test case...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class So36546646Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(So36546646Application.class, args);
        ctx.getBean("out", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        boolean received = ctx.getBean(MyService.class).latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (!received) {
            System.err.println("Did not receive ack");
        }
        ctx.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class).deleteQueue(ctx.getBean(Queue.class).getName());
        ctx.close();
    }

    public static class MyService {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public void handle(Message<?> ack) {
            System.out.println("ack:" + ack);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="cf" publisher-confirms="true" publisher-returns="true" host="localhost" />

    <rabbit:template id="t" connection-factory="cf" mandatory="true" />

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="cf" />

    <rabbit:queue id="anon" />

    <int:channel id="out" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="out"
        amqp-template="t"
        routing-key="#{anon.name}"
        confirm-correlation-expression="payload"
        confirm-ack-channel="acks"
        confirm-nack-channel="acks"
        return-channel="returns" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="acks" ref="service" />

    <bean id="service" class="com.example.So36546646Application$MyService" />

    <int:channel id="returns">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

</beans>
```

and it worked fine:

```
ack:GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=5eed89bf-11b6-76a5-34ed-0091c6bac2c8, timestamp=1460464254229}]
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I removed the call backs and also am setting the publish-confirms=true. Still my ack channel is not getting invoked. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: See my edit - works just fine for me; try running mine and yours with DEBUG logging and compare the logs.